# C++ Program Runs in IDE but not Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, c++14

So I've written a basic C++ program, as I'm still learning C++. The code works when I build and run in the IDE, it opens up a terminal with it working and that's fine.

However, when I source the file and run it in terminal, it doesn't work and here's the errors I get. Any help would be much appreciated.

PS: Spoke to my professor and I am running the newest C++ standards for the course so I now its not that.

Below I've linked what im doing and maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

To Run:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
./main
```

Here's a picture of my errors

[image]

Here's My Code:

```
#Include <iostream>
#using namespace std;

int main() {

const double usd_per_eur {1.19};    

cout << "\nWelcome To Imran's EUR -> USD Converter" << endl;
cout << "Please Enter A Value in EUR: ";

double euros{0.0};
double dollars{0.0};

cin >> euros;
dollars = euros * usd_per_eur;

cout << euros << " Euros is equivalent to " << dollars << "dollars" << endl;

cout << endl; 
return 0; 

}
```

Comment: `g++` **`-std=c++14`** `-Wall main.cpp -o main` (or `c++11` should be sufficient, but since you tagged this with `c++14`...)

Comment: Awesome this actually fixed what I was needing to do! Thanks

Comment: It might be worth updating GCC. Newer versions have C++14 as the default and are more likely to better support everything anyway. By the way, the newest standard is C++17.

Comment: A note: It is almost always best to paste in the error messages as text, not as an image. This does not appear to be one of those rare exceptions. For more on this see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) With the exception of compiling, the same applies to error messages.

Comment: "Spoke to my professor and I am running the newest C++ standards for the course so I now its not that." Careful ... this is exactly what it was. The command line option `-std=c++14` enables that support.

Comment: By the way, you might be able to see the commands that the IDE is running when it builds and launches your program. You could then use those same commands at the command line, as well as look up their meaning in documentation to hopefully understand what's going on behind the scenes a little better.